# Using ZURB foundation from own repo

Tags: gruntjs, npm, zurb-foundation, bower

I don't understand how to compile foundation with my own SASS additions.

I have my own Github repo with ZURB foundation 5, I've extended it (with SASS and JS) and changed some things.
Let's say my repo is here: github.com/some_name/my_foundation_version.

So, I download it from git
`git clone git://github.com/some_name/my_foundation_version`
but then what?

I don't understand how to use bower or grunt in this case. How do I use my own git repo?

**UPDATE:**
Going into: ./foundation/scss and run `sass foundation.scss:output.css` doesn't work either

Comment: if you have compass installed in it ..browse to your directory in local machine -and use `compass watch` it will compile the sass additions

Comment: Thanks, but that's exactly what I don't understand. If I go to: foundation/scss/ or foundation/ this `compass watch` outputs: Nothing to compile

So my question is, how can I simply only compile the sass from the file

Answer (score 0):

**Method One - Self Compile using koala etc**

If you just want to use the scss to compile yourself you need 2 repo's not one

First you want the Foundation Master Repo Then Secondly The Bower_components

[Foundation Master](https://github.com/zurb/foundation)

[Bower-Foundation](https://github.com/zurb/bower-foundation)

Unpack the foundation master then in it create a directory called foundation and unpack the bower components into there.

I personally then use [koala](http://koala-app.com/) to compile the scss which is a simple drag and drop programme I click on the app.scss set the output path to app.css and away I go.

If you want a version to play here is a repo i'm playing with for a framework also has the icons set and a few other bits in there but you can simply download unzip and it should then compile

https://github.com/Relution-Design/legion-assets

I also use netbeans which is more or less the same process, make sure correct libs are installed in netbeans set output path and compile on save.

**Method 2**

Firstly Make sure that you have all the dependencies!! 3 months I spent and was missing one . . . . HEAD IN HANDS :(  then follow the instructions

[FOUNDATION SCSS](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html)